# When packaging jars with RPM, is it a good idea to specify "noarch"?

Tags: java, jar, rpm

My understanding is that jars can run on any platform provided you have a JVM, thus, should any packages that are simple jars be given "noarch" so the rpm can be used on more machines?

Comment: I would imagine so, but I haven't use RPMs to distribute JARs before as they are packages in themselves.

Comment: Oh I see. We are doing it so we can have all software managed by rpm in order to make it easier to deploy whatever we need on our clustered computers.

Comment: That makes sense in that case. If you are using *pure* Java deployment I wouldn't bother.

Comment: I suggest to look how packaging of java rpm packages happens in Fedora. The build process from sources itself, using maven or ant, is managed through rpmbuild

Answer (score 3):

Unless your package contains JNI (Java Native Interface) parts you should always use **BuildArch: noarch**. That way you will get single RPM that can be installed on any architecture .

That says nothing about working on any architecture of course. There are simple ways to screw up multiarch promises of Java & JVM (typically hardcoding in architecture specific assumptions into code). But from packaging point of view, noarch is the default in Java world.